# Laravel load related class model

Tags: php, laravel-5

I need a comprehensive explanation on this excerpt from Martin Bean Laravel Essential :

```
  $breed = Furbook\Breed::with('cats') 
- >whereName($name) 
- >first()
```

I understand all the method except with(). Pls explain in sql what the with('cat') is used for. 
Pls my code might not be formatted well because I used the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), you will see 'with' is for eager loading. It could be explained as follows.

```
select * from books where id = 1

select * from books where id = 2

select * from books where id = 3

select * from books where id = 4
....
```

This query is reduce to

```
select * from books

select * from authors where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...)
```

which is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

`with()` method add the relation to the selected Model.Reference [Laravel Builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_with)

> Set the relationships that should be eager loaded.

Basically, it joins the base table (one on which you are executing the query. In your case **'Breed'**. ) with the one passed to the `with()` method as an argument. (In your case **'cats'**).